# A Good jQuery Image Slideshow - (Like the jQuery Cycle plugin)

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I know....everyone is looking for a good jQuery slideshow.  Let me be clear that I'm not looking for a slideshow like [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net). I'm needing an inline, automatically rotating slideshow like [Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/).
I've just finished scouring the web, and I've seen alot of good ones, but I've had to discard most of them for this reason:

1. I need a slideshow that allows for a fixed container that centers (horizontally and vertically) images that have different sizes.
2. I need to be able to wrap the image in an hyperlink to direct users to the image specific url.

I thought that [Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) was going to work but it ended up failing my requirements as well. By examining Cycle's js file, I see where the active slide's css.left and css.top is forced to: 0. The destroys my possibility of centering the slides inside their container.

Thanks in advance for your input!

Comment: You can cycle some divs and center the images inside the divs as you need.